# Why many applications close after opening a document or doing a specific actions?

Tags: microsoft-word, adobe-reader, documents

I have some encrypted pdf files that have no problem and in my last windows, I could open them easily with Adobe Reader 9.2 and other pdf readers.

But now, I can only open non-encrypted pdf files and one encrypted file with Adobe Reader.
**every time I open almost any encrypted pdf, it closes itself.**

Also, when I try to search a folder for a keyword with Foxit Reader, **once it closed.**

This is not related to Adobe Reader, because I have the same problem with Word 2007.
**When I open a document, sometimes it closes instantly and sometimes it closes after a few seconds and sometimes it is stable.**

My windows is Fresh. I have installed it a few days ago. I have ESET Smart Security 5.2 and I have updated it today.

OS: XP Pro SP3,
RAM: 3 GB,
CPU: 2 GHZ,
HDD: 320 GB

My installed applications:

```
Adobe AIR
Adobe Flash Player 11 ActiveX
Adobe Flash Player 11 Plugin
Adobe Photoshop CS4
Adobe Reader 9.2
Atheros Wireless LAN Client Adapter
Babylon
Bluetooth Stack for Windows by Toshiba
CCleaner
Conexant HD Audio
Dell Touchpad
ESET Smart Security
Farsi (101) Custom
Foxit Reader
Framing Studio 3.27
Google Chrome
Hard Disk Sentinel PRO
HDAUDIO Soft Data Fax Modem with SmartCP
Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator Driver
IrfanView (remove only)
Java(TM) 6 Update 18
K-Lite Mega Codec Pack 8.8.0
Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 1
Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 1
Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5
Microsoft Data Access Components KB870669
Microsoft Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies
Microsoft Office Enterprise 2007
Microsoft User-Mode Driver Framework Feature Pack 1.0.0 (Pre-Release 5348)
Mozilla Firefox 7.0.1 (x86 en-US)
Notepad++
Office Tab FreeEdition 8.50
ParsQuran
PerfectDisk 12 Professional
Registry First Aid
RICOH R5C83x/84x Flash Media Controller Driver Ver.3.54.06
Sahar Money Manager 2.5
Stickies 7.1d
The KMPlayer (remove only)
TurboLaunch 5.1.2
Unlocker 1.9.1
USB Safely Remove 4.2
Virastyar
Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office Second Edition Runtime
Winamp
Windows Internet Explorer 8
Windows Media Player 11.0.5358.4826
Windows XP Service Pack 3
WinRAR 4.11 (32-bit)
WorkPause 1.2
Z Dictionary
```

My startup applications:

```
WorkPause
USB Safely Remove
TurboLaunch
SunJavaUpdateSched
Stickies
rfagent
Persistence
ParsQuran Daily Verse
ITSecMng
IgfxTray
HotKeysCmds
Hard Disk Sentinel
egui
disable shift+delete
CTFMON.EXE
Bluetooth Manager
Babylon Client
Apoint
AdobeCS4ServiceManager
Adobe Reader Speed Launcher
Adobe ARM
```

What should I do to solve it?
If you recommend installing Windows again, what guarantees that it won't happen again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be caused by any of the software which you have installed. It can even be a problem of Windows itself. You can try uninstalling all the programs one by one and maybe it will stop happening after you uninstall one specific program and you will find the program that is "guilty".  Another possibility is that it's caused by hardware. You could install another Windows on your PC (Win 2000, Vista, 7...) and install all of the software that you have installed on this sysem - Win XP. Win 2000 would probably be the best choice since it's more similar to Win XP comparing to Vista and 7. However if I were you, I would format the hard drive and install Windows XP from scratch and then be cautious after installing every single software. Once it starts happening, you know it is the last installed software that causes it. It will save your time...

Comment: Thanks! I found this before your post. The problem was with the HIPS features of ESET Smart Security. I disabled it and everything returned to its normal mode.

Comment: If you know how to disable Firewall in ESET Smart Security forever, let me know, please... I'm using Windows Firewall and every time when I turn on my PC I have to disable Firewall in ESET Smart Security manually...

Comment: Ask another question, not as a comment. Your will have more chance of getting an answer. However, I don't think it is possible. Why do you want to do that? It has many useful options to meet your needs.

"The Personal firewall is a tightly integrated feature of the ESET Smart Security solution and cannot be permanently disabled."
Source: http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=soln564

Comment: I cannot, I am banned from asking questions on SuperUser. ;o) It will probably take few months until they let me ask questions again...

Comment: There are many other places: Yahoo Answers, ask.com, computerhope.com and many other places.